# How do I return an array of pointers in a function?

Tags: c++

So I have an array of pointers that references 3 instances of a class, I need to create a function that gets the references to those 3 instances and returns it into that array.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cinttypes>
#include<random>

//Random number generator
uint8_t rand(uint8_t max){
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> distribution(0,max);

    return distribution(generator);
}

class MyClass{
    //...
}
myClass[100];

MyClass * getReferences(){ //What should the type of this be?
    MyClass * arrayOfPointers[3];

    for(uint8_t i=0;i<2;++i){
        arrayOfPointers[i]=&myClass[rand(2)];
    }

    return arrayOfPointers;
}

int main(){
    MyClass * arrayOfPointers[3]=getReferences();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::array` and your problems will disappear.

Comment: So you've got a local array on the stack and then you return a pointer to it. Function finishes. Array goes out of scope. Nothing works as expected. Probably the most duplicated question on SO after comparing strings in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned you are returning a pointer to a local variable which is incorrect.

Use standard library containers to avoid the pitfalls and woes of C-style arrays.

```
std::array<MyClass *, 3> getReferences()
{
    std::array<MyClass *, 3> arrayOfPointers;

    for(int i=0; i < 2; ++i) // don't use tiny int types of small for loops. it's not faster and it's harder to maintain
    {
        arrayOfPointers[i] = &myClass[rand(2)];
    }

    return arrayOfPointers;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<MyClass *, 3> arrayOfPointers = getReferences();
}
```

Comment: I was unaware of there being a standard library container for arrays, thanks! Also, so there is no advantage to using a small int type for a for loop? What about using uint_fast8_t then?

Comment: @TriforceOfKirby Why do you want to use an 8-bit value at all? It means whenever you change the range of the for loop, you also have to check the counter type is big enough, which is enough possibility of error. What `uint_fast8_t` actually is, is up to the compiler.

Comment: Well I suppose I just don't want to allocate more memory than needed. I find it fairly easy to determine if the type is large enough at a glance; the types are guaranteed to be at least the size specified or larger correct? If it needs to be made larger it's only 1 number to change.

Comment: For ~3 bytes? Compiler is free to, and indeed may, secretly convert your byte to a 4-byte int (or some other type) as an optimization, as smaller types may be slower to process. This is my advice as a seasoned programmer.

Comment: In most compilers you can control optimization preferences. So is execution speed in general more important than memory usage?

Comment: When the saving is 3 bytes, yes. If you were storing 10,000 integers that were only 0-255, then it would be more sensible to store them as 8-bit.

Comment: Ok, so would it be sensible to use `uint_fast_t` types? As it will use the fastest type that is at least the specified width. Also, thanks for all the information.

Comment: A general for loop, I would use `int`. A for loop which needs to iterate over a data structure, I would use either iterators (preferably - removes all consideration of what counter type to use) or `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

Returning a pointer to a local variable is incorrect in C++. It can lead in memory violation errors. If you want to return an array from the function you should use dynamic memory allocation. `MyClass * arrayOfPointers = new MyClass[3];`. Don't forget to delete it, after using. `delete[] arrayOfPointers;`

Comment: If you want to return an array from the function you should NOT use dynamic memory allocation using `new[]`. What bad advice!

Comment: Why? Probably, you should not if you use exceptions inside the function.

Comment: "Don't forget to delete it" - which is exactly why you shouldn't be throwing raw pointers around and hoping for the best. Return `std::vector` if you need a dynamic array; but for a tiny, fixed-size array like this, dynamic allocation is massively inefficient, so return a `std::array`.

Comment: Yes std::vector or std::array would be better.